# Register multiple singletons with same interface but different constructor parameters values

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-topics

I got stuck and need some advice or pointer to a solution.

A web API with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<ITopicClient>(s => new TopicClient({connectionstring},{topic}));
```

TopicRepository.cs

```
 public class TopicRepository : ITopicRepository
 {
        private readonly ITopicClient _topicClient1;
       private readonly ITopicClient _topicClient2;

        public TopicRepository (ITopicClient topicClient1, ITopicClient topicClient2)
        {         
            _topicClient1 = topicClient1;
            _topicClient2 = topicClient2;
        }
        public async Task<Response> SendToTopicAsync(string message, string topic)
        {
           if( topic == "topic1")
           await _topicClient1.send(message);
           else if (topic == "topic2")
           await _topicClient2.send(message);
        }
}
```

TopicClient.cs in a **shared library**

```
        public TopicClient(string serviceBusConnectionString, string topicName)
        {
           _topicClient = new TopicClient(_serviceBusConnectionString,topicName);
        }
```

I need to send message to different topics. I would like to register services with different topic names in startup.cs. I want to reuse topicClient connection.

services.AddSingleton(s => new TopicClient({connectionstring},{**topic1**}));

services.AddSingleton(s => new TopicClient({connectionstring},{**topic2**}));

How can I achieve this by registering singleton instances of same type using same interface ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need a service for each topic, what you need is some connection factory that is responsible for managing your single connection then you inject that into your services and call that to return the connection for you.

Comment: Or create a type for each topic and register a Topic123TopicClient for each one.  Like database connection strings, your app probably uses a small, fixed set of Topics.

Comment: Is there any other way that I could implement, becasue at present I need TopicClient instances for only 5 topics, but down the line it may grow.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a client resolver that holds your registered clients with a wrapper around the client.
First create a wrapper around your client with a name or enum for how to resolve it. As I'm not a fan of magic strings I decided to go with an enum in the example.

```
// Wrapper for your TopicClients
public interface ICustomTopicClient
{
    public ITopicClient TopicClient { get; }
    public TopicName TopicName { get; }
}

// Implement the ICustomTopicClient interface
public class CustomTopicClient : ICustomTopicClient
{
    public ITopicClient TopicClient { get; }
    public TopicName TopicName { get; }
    
    public CustomTopicClient(ITopicClient topicClient, TopicName topicName)
    {
        TopicClient = topicClient;
        TopicName = topicName;
    }
}

// Enum for how to resolve the requested TopicClient
public enum TopicName
{
    Topic1 = 0,
    Topic2 = 1
}

// Register all ICustomTopicClients in your container
services.AddSingleton<ICustomTopicClient>(s => new CustomTopicClient(new TopicClient({connectionstring},{topic}), TopicName.Topic1));
services.AddSingleton<ICustomTopicClient>(s => new CustomTopicClient(new TopicClient({connectionstring},{topic2}), TopicName.Topic2));
```

Then you create a resolver that holds all custom clients.
You inject the collection of clients from the container and create a dictionary with a public method to resolve the clients.

```
public interface IMessageClientResolver
{
    ITopicClient ResolveClient(TopicName name);
}

public class MessageClientResolver : IMessageClientResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TopicName, ITopicClient> topicClients;

    public MessageClientResolver(IEnumerable<ICustomTopicClient> clients)
    {
         topicClients = clients.ToDictionary(k => k.TopicName, v => v.TopicClient);
    }

    public ITopicClient ResolveClient(TopicName name)
    {
        topicClients.TryGetValue(name, out var client);
        if (client is null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(client));

        return client;
    }
}
```

Register the resolver to the container.

```
services.AddSingleton<IMessageClientResolver, MessageClientResolver>();
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ITopicClient topicClient;
    private readonly ITopicClient topicClient2;

    public Foo(IMessageClientResolver clientResolver)
    {
        topicClient = clientResolver.ResolveClient(TopicName.Topic1);
        topicClient2 = clientResolver.ResolveClient(TopicName.Topic2);
    }
}
```

You can use the same pattern and extend the resolver with IQueueClients. And add a resolve method to return the IQueueClient by a QueueName enum.

Answer (score 4):

You can already register multiple instances as the same interface, so when you do:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITopicClient>(_ => new TopicClient("topic1"));
services.AddSingleton<ITopicClient>(_ => new TopicClient("topic2"));
```

you already added **two** instances to the container.

It is just when you resolve interface `ITopicClient`, you always get the last added instance. For example, if you resolve:

```
// instance = topic2
var instance = container.GetService<ITopicClient>();
```

If you need all instances, you should resolve / inject `IEnumerable<ITopicClient>`.

```
class TopicRepository
{
    public TopicRepository(IEnumerable<ITopicClient> clients)
    {
        // clients contains topic1 and topic2
    }
}
```